# JS calculator bug

Tags: javascript

P.S new to js,
I made an ios like calculator in js in which the basic functioning is the user enters the first number which gets stored in a variable , screen gets cleared then the user enters the second number which again needs to be stored in a variable. I am currently having problem in storing the second number.

---

```
    const getnum = () => {
  let firstnum = parseFloat(ans.innerText);
  console.log("firstnum" + "=" + firstnum);
};
```

Copied this from internet to get the second number

```
operationperf = (operation) => {
  if (!numinmem) {
    numinmem = parseFloat(ans.textContent);
    operatorinmem = operation;
    ans.textContent = "";
    return;
  }
  operatorinmem = operation;
  ans.textContent = getResultOfOperationAsStr();
  ans.textContent = "";
};
```

---

but this causes both the variables to have the same value so if i do 50+78 the calculator performs 50+50

working demo: https://megahedron69.github.io/ios-Calculator/
javascript file: https://github.com/Megahedron69/ios-Calculator/blob/main/app.js

Comment: Please post a [mcve] here, not a link to an external site. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it seems that your `numinmem` variable is not being used outside the scope of `operationperf` function for any further processing.

Also, in your following function:

```
const getResultOfOperationAsStr = () => {
  const currentValueNum = parseFloat(ans.textContent);
  const valueNumInMemory = parseFloat(ans.textContent);
  let newValueNum;
  if (operatorinmem === "addition") {
    newValueNum = valueNumInMemory + currentValueNum;
  } else if (operatorinmem === "subtraction") {
    newValueNum = valueNumInMemory - currentValueNum;
  } else if (operatorinmem === "multiplication") {
    newValueNum = valueNumInMemory * currentValueNum;
  } else if (operatorinmem === "division") {
    newValueNum = valueNumInMemory / currentValueNum;
  }
  return newValueNum.toString();
};
```

It appears that your are using the current value of the element stored in `ans` variable for both sides of your operations (e.g. `ansValueAsFloat + ansValueAsFloat`), hence, producing the undesired behavior.

My recommendation would be to set any of the variables involved in the final operation to the value of `numinmem` and set the other to the current value in `ans`.

Hope I made myself clear.